# API request does not randomize and does not display

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I am having trouble with a button that fetches a random user from an API. When retrieving all users the information is displayed without a hiccup, however when one is selected at random it does not work. Also it does not randomize each time it just remains as one user.
Error message: `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'John Doe'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`
`service file`:

```
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
random(){
   return this._httpClient.get(`${this.placeholderApi}/users/${this.randomNumber}`)
}
```

`html file:`

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users" class="container emp-profile">
   <h5>
      {{user.name}}
   </h5>
```

`users.component.ts`

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users;

  getRandomUser() {
    this.clearUsers()
    this._dataService.random().subscribe(
      result => this.users = result
    )
  }

  clearUsers() {
    this.users = null 
  }
```

Comment: Well seems that when you get a random user you get just one object (which makes sense) You are trying to iterate that like an array.

Comment: @AJT_82 Yes! That makes sense. When calling one person it is an object but with multiple it is an array. Is it possible to make users dynamic to both act as an array and object depending on circumstance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we established, you are just getting one object when retrieving a random user, which means Angular will throw an error about `*ngFor` trying to iterate that object. The easiest solution I see, is when you get a user, just push it to the `users` array. That means no changes in template.

Also then, when clearing array, set it as an empty array, otherwise angular would complain about trying to push to `undefined`. I personally also always like to initialize/clear an array by setting it as empty.

So do the following changes:

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users = [];

  getRandomUser() {
    this.users = [];
    this._dataService.random().subscribe(
      result => this.users.push(result)
      // or this.users = [result] // which wouldn't throw undefined error
    )
  }
```

So now your `users` remains as an array!

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot for taking the time to fix this problem. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)